# cleaning up session table in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to store all the sessions in my db, I want to be able to tell if the users latest session has expired.

I tried this but as you can imagine all the sessions that where less the < current time showed.

```
"SELECT userid FROM session WHERE expiretime < '".date()."'"
```

basiclly i need to group the userid I know that.
Then I need it to only limit 1 per userid
Then I need to make sure it is the last session id

**CORRECT WAY TO DO THIS!**
Ok I figured it out to do this you need to use IN

```
SELECT * FROM `user_sessions` WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) as id FROM `user_sessions` GROUP BY userid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `user_sessions` WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) as id FROM `user_sessions` GROUP BY userid)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule.
To do something, one has to know what are they doing.
That's extremely handy principle, always helps me.

For example, if I want to compare some date stored in my database, **I have to know what format it is**. Is it a unix timestamp or datetime or some custom format?
Next thing I'd have to know is what is PHP `date()` function output when called without parameters and if it match database format. And if it's just an error message - than how to make it match with database format (I'd read a documentation page for this).
Sounds sensible? I hope so.

Next thing I would research is how to perform *date calculations* in mysql. It seems I will need some comparison using mysql function DATE_SUB()

Honestly, are you sure you want your custom session storage? A regular one already doing all this job for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the MySQL [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function.

```
"SELECT userid FROM session WHERE expiretime < NOW()"
```